# IIS Error - Invalid Path

Tags: iis

I am new to IIS and trying to set up a site on it. I am trying to set up `Microsft.Hosting.SharePoint2010.Services`. I keep getting the following error.

[image: Error]

Here are my Basic Settings. The physical path is `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Hosting\Microsoft.Hosting.SharePoint2010\Microsoft.Hosting.SharePoint2010.Services` which actually exists on the computer. I get the error above when I click the Test Settings button. I suppose for some reason it is not serving this folder. Does anyone have any ideas?

[image: Error]

Comment: What credentials are being used to connect to that physical location on disk?

Comment: @Matthew Abbott It is connection as the Application User. It is the full SharePoint administrator. Should have full privileges.